# How to convert while loop to for loop in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

```
list_from=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list_from2=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]
from_dict={list_from[i]:list_from2[i] for i in range(len(list_from2))}
list_to = [1,2,5,10]
save=[]
num=0
while num<=len(list_to):
    try:
        if list_to[num] in list_from:
            save.append(from_dict[list_to[num]])
        else:
            save.append('')
       num+=1
   except:
        break
```

I have the code like the above. I want to convert this while loop code to for loop.
(Also, if possible, I want convert to list comprehension code)
How can I do this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think i had a mistake the code. It seems empty list 'save' enter twice. Sorry about that.

Comment: for number in list_from

Comment: `from_dict = dict(zip(list_from, list_from2))` would be simpler.

Comment: as would `save = [from_dict.get(x, '') for x in list_to]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just replace your

```
num = 0
while num <= len(list_to):
```

By

```
for num in range(0, len(list_to)):
```

This way, your variable "num" would automatically take value `0`, then `1`, ... `len(list_to)-1`

Answer (score 1):

With For loop

```
for i in range(len(list_to)):
    if list_to[i] in list_from:
        save.append(from_dict[list_to[i]])
    else:
        save.append('')
```